# How do I fix my sveltekit website throwing 500 errors when reloading it?

Tags: svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit, internal-server-error, http-status-code-500

When Hosting my Website on cloudflare pages it is throwing 500 errors when reloading it.
When I host it locally in my dev env it works just fine.
I fetch data from a pocketbase database i am hosting and this error will only be thrown on pages that try to fetch data in a +page.ts load function from said database.

+page.ts

```
export const load = async () => {
  const carCollection = await pb.collection("cars")

  return {
    carCollection: carCollection,
    cars: writable((await carCollection.getList()).items),
    user: pb.authStore.model?.id,
  }
}
```

+page.svelte

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { invalidate, invalidateAll } from "$app/navigation"
  export let data
  let cars = data.cars
  let carInput: HTMLInputElement
  const carCollection = data.carCollection
  $: cars = data.cars
</script>
```

I have been trying to fix this for a while now.
Tried to do some simple debugging but I am not really getting anywhere.
Also I tried to use `if (browser)` but this did not do anything for me but its possible I used it wrong so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Havent't tried Pocketbase for a while, but maybe it is not reachable from a client ? Try putting the load function in a `+page.server.js` file to ensure it is executed on the server.

Comment: I tried to host it on netlify and it works just fine so there it goes.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to host it on netlify and it works just fine so there it goes.